# Ruby gem installation stuck on Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, debian, nokogiri

I'm trying to do a `bundle install` but the installation seems to be getting stuck on Nokogiri 1.6.3.1.

The operating system is Raspbian on Raspberry Pi, and the Ruby version is 1.9.3.

Here is the output:

```
$ sudo bundle install
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........
Fetching additional metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using multi_json 1.10.0
Using activesupport 3.2.18
Using builder 3.0.4
Using activemodel 3.2.18
Using addressable 2.3.6
Using gyoku 1.1.1
Using mini_portile 0.6.0
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Building libxml2-2.8.0 for nokogiri with the following patches applied:
        - 0001-Fix-parser-local-buffers-size-problems.patch
        - 0002-Fix-entities-local-buffers-size-problems.patch
        - 0003-Fix-an-error-in-previous-commit.patch
        - 0004-Fix-potential-out-of-bound-access.patch
        - 0005-Detect-excessive-entities-expansion-upon-replacement.patch
        - 0006-Do-not-fetch-external-parsed-entities.patch
        - 0007-Enforce-XML_PARSER_EOF-state-handling-through-the-pa.patch
        - 0008-Improve-handling-of-xmlStopParser.patch
        - 0009-Fix-a-couple-of-return-without-value.patch
        - 0010-Keep-non-significant-blanks-node-in-HTML-parser.patch
        - 0011-Do-not-fetch-external-parameter-entities.patch
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT!  Nokogiri builds and uses a packaged version of libxml2.

If this is a concern for you and you want to use the system library
instead, abort this installation process and reinstall nokogiri as
follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

However, note that nokogiri does not necessarily support all versions
of libxml2.

For example, libxml2-2.9.0 and higher are currently known to be broken
and thus unsupported by nokogiri, due to compatibility problems and
XPath optimization bugs.
************************************************************************
```

What should I do? Should I wait a while? It doesn't give me any errors, unless I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: How long did you wait for it to compile? I'm sure on a Pi it would take some time. As it states, it needs to compile `libxml2`.

Comment: Wait - this isn't an error, every Nokogiri build will do this.  Their library is huge, it will take some time, especially on a Pi.

Comment: Ok Thank you, I waited about 20 minutes,